# Probability P[X,X+Y] where X and Y independent

Tags: probability

Given X and Y two independent random variables with densities $p_X$ and $p_Y$ I want to write the joint probability $P[X,X+Y]$.

What I do is:

1) $P[X,X+Y]=P[X+Y|X]P[X]$ by conditional probability formula

2) $P[X+Y|X]=\int p_Y(y-x)dy$

3) $P[X,X+Y]=\int\int p_Y(y-x) p_X(x)dydx$

**Doubts**: I am not really sure of the step 2) above. My reasoning is that since X and Y are independent then given a value of X the distribution of X+Y is just $\int p_Y(y-x)dy$. Could someone here confirm or correct this, please.

Comment: why don't you use transformation method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your notation $P[X,X+Y]$ is ...unusual to say the least.   You are also using indefinite integrals, which appears to be confusing you.

However, as it is seems that you mean the joint cumulative distribution, which is:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P_{X,X+Y}(s, t) & = \mathsf P(X\leq s, X+Y\leq t)
\\[1ex] &= \int_{-\infty}^s \mathsf P(Y\leq t-X\mid X=x)\,p_X(x)\operatorname d x & \text{conditioning}
\\[1ex] &= \int_{-\infty}^s \mathsf P(Y\leq t-x)\,p_X(x)\operatorname d x & \text{independence}
\\[1ex] &= \int_{-\infty}^s\int_{-\infty}^{t-x} p_Y(y)\,p_X(x)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x
\end{align}$$